# unable to download file from my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to download file from MySQL server, but am not able to do so.

The script executes but it can download only the first 65 KB of the file.

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result  = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $name=$row['name'];
            $size=$row['size'];
            $type=$row['type'];
            $content=$row['content'];
        }
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
        header("Content-length: $size");
        header("Content-type: $type");
        echo $content;
    } else {
        die("No file id given...");
    }
    unset($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Comment: What is the type of your `size` column? `SMALLINT`?

Comment: its bigint @u_mulder

Comment: I suppose problem is in saving image to db. You set `Content-length` which is not the same as file size, so, when you set `size` column value - you made a mistake, I suppose

Comment: so what should i do now ..??? @u_mulder

Comment: It is kinda obvious: fix your upload script...

Comment: i am able to upload files into database @Shadow

Comment: See the observation by @u_mulder That mistake is commeted in the upload file.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `content-length`. It needs to be the size of what you transmit.

You want something like this:

```
header( "Content-length: " . count( content) );
```